# Oppeness on projective morphism when fibers are semi-ample

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be projective variety. Consider $\pi:X\to B$ be a projective morphism and take $$\mathcal D=\{b\in B|K_{X_b} \; \; \text{is semi-ample}\}$$ Then when $D$ is open and closed ?

Comment: Since $K_{X_b}$ is semi-ample, hence it is nef. Let $A$ be an $\pi$-ample line bundle on $X$ and let 

$\sigma(X_s,K_{X_b},A)=min(AC|C\;  \text{effective 1-cycle with}\;  K_{X_b}C<0)$. 

The openness of $\mathcal D$ is equivalent to $\{(X_b,K_{A_b},A_b)\}_{b\in B}$ being bounded for some $A$.  See Theorem 1 in  http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN365956996_0075/PPN365956996_0075___LOG_0026.pdf.

I don't have any idea about closedness